# Add captions to my HTML slider

Tags: html, css

How can I add a title or caption that displays a short description unique to each slide on my carousel. Here is my code:

```
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li>SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE3</li>
    <li>SLIDE4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: you may add a div tag inside li elements and add text there.

Comment: "Caption" meaning what? Text near the `li` elements? There's a million and one ways to accomplish that, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Caption meaning a short description unique to each slide on the bottom portion of the slide that the user can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea of adding captions would be using HTML and CSS:

```css
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;}
li {position: relative; width: 150px; height: 150px; list-style: none; display: inline-block; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #999; line-height: 150px; margin-bottom: 0.25em;}
li .caption {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25); line-height: 3em;}
```

```html
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">&gt;</a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">&lt;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      SLIDE 1
      <div class="caption">Caption 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      SLIDE 2
      <div class="caption">Caption 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      SLIDE 3
      <div class="caption">Caption 3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      SLIDE 4
      <div class="caption">Caption 4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Should code this allow me to have each caption be unique to each slide or will each caption be the same ? @Viren B.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a title to each `<li>` tag:

```
<li title="This is a caption">SLIDE 1</li>
```

Comment: Would I use the "title" class for both a title and a caption ? @zack.lore

Comment: In my example the SLIDE 1 text would act as the title and when the user hovered over the `<li>` tag they would see the caption that you provide using `title="Caption you want the user to see"` within each `<li>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much . Your example was very helpful.